# Image of a ray under nice function

Tags: real-analysis

Is the image of ray under bijective continuous map from $ \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ a ray?

Obviously such a function takes compact/connected sets to compact/connected sets, as well as open to open, closed to closed, etc. But how do we show that the actual "length" is preserved?

Perhaps using sequences somehow?

Seems trivial, but I'm not really sure...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is yes: a ray is mapped to a ray. I have no comment on the vague "length" remark.

A bijective continuous map $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is either strictly increasing or strictly decreasing. For definiteness, consider the strictly increasing case. Then the order is preserved: $f(x)>f(y)$ *if and only if* $x>y$. Therefore, the set $\{x:x>a\}$ is mapped onto $\{y:y>f(a)\}$. Same for closed interval.

Answer (score 0):

The length is not preserved.  $\mathbb{R}$ is homeomorphic to an open interval $(a,b)$.  Length is not preserved.

Comment: We want a function from R to R here though that is bijective.